# find same combination of values in array and add quantity

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have following array:

```
   [2865] => Array
        (
            [product] => 17
            [quantity] => 5
            [option_24] => 51
            [option_28] => 63
            [option_25] => 53
        )

    [2866] => Array
        (
            [product] => 17
            [quantity] => 5
            [option_24] => 51
            [option_28] => 63
            [option_25] => 53
        )

    [2867] => Array
        (
            [product] => 20
            [quantity] => 1
            [option_29] => 65
            [option_30] => 67
            [option_31] => 71
        )
```

Now I want to get addition of those quantity which array is having same values. For eg-
array `2866` and array `2867` having same options_ values `(51,63,53)`. So I want to add quantity of this arrays.

i.e `5 + 1 =6`.

Comment: In foreach I stored first array in temp and compare temp array with second one.. but no luck..

Comment: `array_keys($arr[2866]) != array_keys($arr[2867])`

Comment: Why would you calculate the quantity as `5 + 1 = 6`, when both records have quantity `5`? Error in the example or omission in the description of the logic?